# Getting empty response from backend - Gatewayscript

Tags: rest, api-gateway, apiconnect

I have to get the details of an agent from backend server based on agent_id. We are passing few input parameters in headers. i want to get the request ID number in case of error. I have written the gateway script as below:

```
// Define modules
var sm   = require('service-metadata.js');
var hm   = require('header-metadata.js');
var apim = require('./apim.custom.js'); 

var LegacyAgentNumber = apim.getvariable('request.parameters.LegacyAgentNumber');
var requestId = apim.getvariable('request.parameters.requestId');
var channelId = apim.getvariable('request.parameters.channelId');
var channelName = apim.getvariable('request.parameters.channelName');
var sm_user = apim.getvariable('request.parameters.sm_user');

// To send as query parameters
var queryString = '$filter=contains(LegacyAgentNumber,%27'+legacyAgentNumber+'%27)';

apim.setvariable('queryString', queryString);
apim.setvariable('requestId', requestId);
apim.setvariable('channelId', channelId);
apim.setvariable('channelName', channelName);
apim.setvariable('sm_user', sm_user);

var contentType = apim.getvariable('request.headers.content-type');
apim.setvariable(sm_user, contentType, 'set');

if (error) {

     {
//here I want to print the requestID from headers as values in errorId and refidRequest fields.
"errorId": "{requestId}Err",

"refidRequest": "{requestId}",

"httpCode": "400",

"httpMessage": "Bad Request",

"moreInformation": "Invalid Input Parameters"

} 

else {

        // read response data

        // get the response status code

        var vid = apim.getvariable ('request.parameters.id');
var vapiversion = apim.getvariable('api.version');
var vapiname = apim.getvariable('api.name');


var sresponse= {"AgentMailingAddressKeepAliveResponse": {"responseHeader": {
   "id": vid +"_rs",
   "refidRequest": vid,
   "cmdType": "response",
   "cmdStatus": "Success",
   "message": "keepAlive response message "+vapiname+":"+vapiversion
}}}
apim.setvariable('message.body',response);
apim.setvariable('message.headers.content-type','application/json');
apim.setvariable('message.status.code',200);
```

Here is the URI :
[https://dev.blah.com:port/enterprise/dev/agencies/agency/books/book/agents/{agent_id}/contact-information?requestId=_123&channelId=OL&channelName=OL](https://dev.blah.com:port/enterprise/dev/agencies/agency/books/book/agents/%7Bagent_id%7D/contact-information?requestId=_123&channelId=OL&channelName=OL)

How do i write the query string for this and achieve to get the details from the target.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have already saved the necessary data in the variables. So did you try a query like below in invoke policy?

```
https://dev.blah.com:port/enterprise/dev/agencies/agency/books/book/agents/$(agentId)/contact-information?requestId=$(requestId)&channelId=$(channelId)&channelName=$(channelName)
```

Also you don't need to use this files:

```
var sm   = require('service-metadata.js');
var hm   = require('header-metadata.js');
var apim = require('./apim.custom.js');
```